# How do I change/delete alias in OS X permanently?

Tags: terminal

I tried to modify/delete alias, but it seems that it is only for the current session by doing this

```
unalias name
```

or rename it

```
unalias name='...'
```

Can anyone tell me the way to change/delete it permanently? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it.
In order to make permanent change to alias, I need to edit a config file.

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Than I enter the GNU nano editor window, then I make the change to the line that I want, maybe delete a line or change a line, for example:

```
alias name='/Applications/FunProfile/GoodProgram'
```

Then press control+o to save it, next press control+x+enter to exit it.